# remove the single quote from json data, highchart dotnet api

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, highcharts

I have the following json data:

```
series: [{
                name: 'Winter 2007-2008',
                pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                data: [
                    '[Date.UTC(2013,10,1),1390640]',
                    '[Date.UTC(2013,10,2),1577267]', 
                    '[Date.UTC(2013,10,3),870361]', 
                    '[Date.UTC(2013,10,4),858799]', .............
```

I am forming this `[Date.UTC(2013,10,4),858799]` data by string manipulation using c#, to use it in highchart graphs.

but graph is not been plotted, because `[Date.UTC(2013,10,4),858799]` contains **'** single quote, when c# string gets rendered.

please help me how to remove single quote from json data.

Comment: Change your code to not do that.

Comment: The [JSON spec](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) says it must use double quotes for strings. This is not valid JSON data in the first place.

Comment: i know it, but i am forming this code by c#, string is replaced with ' single quote, now how do i remove that single quote.

Comment: You need to show the C# where you do the string manipulation...

Comment: You can replace your single quote with double with `Replace` method like `yourstring.Replace("'","''");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain I understand, but if you want to evaluate the date in C# before embedding it in the JSON string, it has to go outside of the double quotes. If you want to evaluate it at the JavaScript side, then it is not *really* JSON at all, but JavaScript, as there are no functions in JSON. The Winter string should also use embedded double quotes if it's JSON, as single quoted strings are not valid in JSON.

```
string javaScriptData =
    "series: [{" +
        "name: 'Winter 2007-2008'," +
        "pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000," +
        "data: [" +
            "[Date.UTC(2013,10,1),1390640]," +
            "[Date.UTC(2013,10,2),1577267]," +
            "[Date.UTC(2013,10,3),870361]," + 
            "[Date.UTC(2013,10,4),858799]," +
        "]" +
    "}]";
```

OR:

```
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
string jsonData =
    "series: [{" +
        "name: \"Winter 2007-2008\"," +
        "pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000," +
        "data: [" +
            "[" + (epoch - new DateTime(2013, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds + ",1390640]," +
            "[" + (epoch - new DateTime(2013, 10, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds + ",1577267]," +
            "[" + (epoch - new DateTime(2013, 10, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds + ",870361]," + 
            "[" + (epoch - new DateTime(2013, 10, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds + ",858799]," +
        "]" +
    "}]";
```

<sub>Disclaimer: I have never used C# or .NET in my life, and I'm just guessing how to get a timestamp out of it. Eek.</sub>

Comment: Date.UTC is javascript function

i just want to remove single quote before and after this value '[Date.UTC(2013,10,1),1390640]'. need help

Comment: i don't tried this code but i found my soution before your post, in the end i copied my the html text in a string variable and replaced ('[ with [) and (]' with ]) by using c# method, .replace("","") method.

Comment: @SanjayBathre Glad you found a solution. Sorry I wasn't more helpful. You don't need to 'accept' my answer if it didn't work.

Comment: please help me for this,

when i am setting [Date.UTC(2013,10,1),1390640] instead of october it shows november, how to sort this problem. please need help.

Comment: @SanjayBathre JavaScript months are 0-based. January is 0. December is 11. So October is 9.

Comment: yeah i found that, but atleast how do i change this indexing.
i have to change it to display the months name correctly on the graph.

Comment: @SanjayBathre Use 9 instead of 10.

Comment: i got the solution
DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers.Tools.GetTotalMilliseconds(2013,10,21),
thanx for replying Boann.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can try to use eval() function, but generally will be better to prepare correct JSON (without Date.UTC()) because in json you cannot have functions.